# how to sort data in Laravel Eloquent query, based on a specific field

Tags: laravel

I have this Eloquent query:

```
$events = Product::forCard()->latest()->take(setting('storefront_recent_products_section_total_products', 10))->get();
```

I want to sort this record in ascending order by `start_event`. I tried to do this, but I have some issues because data come from multiple tables.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [price] => Modules\Support\Money Object
                (
                    [amount:Modules\Support\Money:private] => 
                    [currency:Modules\Support\Money:private] => USD
                )

            [special_price] => 
            [selling_price] => Modules\Support\Money Object
                (
                    [amount:Modules\Support\Money:private] => 
                    [currency:Modules\Support\Money:private] => USD
                )

            [special_price_start] => 
            [special_price_end] => 
            [options_count] => 0
            [id] => 40
            [slug] => -YvHm5m1m
            [in_stock] => 1
            [new_from] => 
            [new_to] => 
            [name] => Race4
            [description] => 
            [organizer] => 
            [short_description] => 
            [address] => 
            [city] => vehari
            [state] => pakistan
            [zip_code] => 
            [lat] => 
            [lng] => 
            [start_event] => 2020-01-13 00:00:00
            [end_event] => 
            [translations] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 33
                            [product_id] => 40
                            [locale] => en
                            [name] => Race4
                            [city] => vehari
                            [state] => pakistan
                            [start_event] => 2020-01-13 00:00:00
                        )

                )

            [files] => Array
                (
                )

        )
```

Comment: "_I have some issues_" is not a problem description. What output do you get? Why is that wrong? What should it be instead?

Comment: Have you tried the `orderBy` option ?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to order is ascending something similiar to this:

```
$events = Product::forCard()->latest()
                            ->take(setting('storefront_recent_products_section_total_products', 10))
                            ->orderBy('start_event', 'asc');
```

Basically you can tell using the method `orderBy()` which column shall be used to order and the type of ordering, in this case ascending.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel makes it easy and absolutely no brainer to sort data.

```
$events = Product::forCard()->latest()->take(setting('storefront_recent_products_section_total_products', 10))
->orderBy('start_event')->get();
```

Where `start_event` is the column you want t use in sorting.

There is a better approach, as the above code will automatically sort the returned data in an **ascending order**, but you can explicitly tell it what to do.

Just modify the last part of the code with:

```
orderBy('start_event', 'ASC')->get(); /** If you want Ascending OR; **/

orderBy('start_event', 'DESC')->get(); /** If you want Descending. **/
```

Comment: data is sorted on the base of primary key but i want to sort on start_event, so thankx  for guideline.